# What is the issue with this VB.NET code "End Of Statement Unexpected"?

Tags: .net, vb.net, division

```
Dim x As Integer = dividedTwoTextBox.Text
If x%2 = 0 Then
    dividedByTwoFinalLabel.Text = "Yeah, It can be divided by two!"
End If
```

I dont know where is the problem, It gives me an End Of Statement unexpected at the part x%2 at the "2" number. What can it be?

Comment: errm, I *think* you want `x/2` instead of `x%2`. `x%` is declaring a variable `x` as an integer, which you already have declared, so the syntax does not make sense

Comment: Also you should switch option strict on

Answer (score 1):

It seems you want to check whether **a number is even or not**, then you need this

```
Dim x As Integer = CInt(dividedTwoTextBox.Text)
If x Mod 2 = 0 Then
    dividedByTwoFinalLabel.Text = "Yeah, It can be divided by two!"
End If
```